# Como colocar el src de una imagen en un modal cuando se edita el formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas tardes my developers. Por favor estoy tratando de colocar una imagen en un modal utilizando jquery al momento de editar el formulario de los datos del empleado.

```js
//Codigo para pasar datos al empleado
$(".editbtn_emp").on("click", function() {
  $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var datos = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
  $("#id_emp").val(datos[0]);
  $("#id_cargo").val(datos[0]);
  $("#nombre").val(datos[2]);
  $("#apellidos").val(datos[3]);
  $("#direccion").val(datos[4]);
  $("#telefono").val(datos[5]);
  $("#ruta_foto").val(datos[6]);
  $("#sexo").val(datos[7]);
  $("#dni").val(datos[8]);
  $("#referencia").val(datos[9]);
  $("#observaciones").val(datos[10]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-7">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="photo">
      <label for="foto">Foto Empleado:</label>
      <div class="prevPhoto">
        <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
        <label for="foto"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="upimg">
        <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
      </div>
      <div id="form_alert">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

necesito no el valor sino el src de la imagen y que se muestre la imagen en el modal

Comment: tu pregunta no es para nada específica, por favor cita todo el código posible o replica el error, podría ser muy relativa la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la `attr`

```
var src = $("#id_que_sea").attr("src");
```

Comment: Mira lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla, según el código jquery que recorre los td pero solo captura los valores de texto y no los de la imagen. Como cuadro eso? Que capture el atributo en esa posición donde esta alojada la imagen?

Comment: Esto no es una critica, ni un comentario, es mi respuesta. El OP dice: "necesito no el valor sino el src de la imagen", con esto lo tiene.